# Subscribing to an Azure topic using TIBCO

Tags: azure, tibco, azure-servicebus-topics, tibco-business-works

How do I subscribe to a Microsoft Azure topic? What are the ways in which I can subscribe?

I do not have any control on the topic creation and messages sent to the topic, I need to subscribe to the topic and get the messages from the topic

The preferred option is from TIBCO, is it possible? How do I go about it? I am using Tibco BW. If not tibco, is it possible to build a Java application for the same?

Couldn't find much help on google with respect to the implementation using Tibco. Any pointers on the approach and possibility will be really helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no straight connection option but you can achieve this by the extension Mechanisms of TIBCO Businessworks.

I used it for Azure Bus Queues but no Topic yet. Basically there's two options:

- Use the Microsoft Azure SDK for Java (e.g. take a look here https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-java-how-to-use-topics-subscriptions/)
- Use the Azure Bus AMQP 1.0 feature and connect it with a typical Java AMQP 1.0 compatible client (e.g. Qpid Client is recommended for Azure). I used this e.g. for Azure Queues and it works quite ok after a starter learning curve.

Both could be wrapped as a custom event source activity in TIBCO Businessworks 5 where you place that listener code for the Azure Topics or via the Plugin API in Businessworks 6.

Out of luck the AMQP option might also via the freely available AMQP plugin for Businessworks 6 (https://tap.tibco.com/storefront/sample-evaluations/tibco-activematrix-businessworks-plug-in-for-amqp-community-edition/prod16143.html)

Hope that helps to get the right pointers

With best regards
           Sebastian

Comment: Thanks. But does this option (Second) require changes on the server side (who creates the topic) - usage of Azure Bus AMQP 1.0 feature.

Comment: Not that i know, topic is topic and queue is queue & it worked with queues + Qpid for me  ;) Here's a nice article on the option with Qpid client. Might work with Businessworks JMS feature as Qpid used as external JMS driver. I would give that one a shot even first: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-amqp-java/

Comment: Thanks. We have decided to go for this option. as mentioned in the above url. I guess the url https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-java-how-to-use-jms-api-amqp/ also talks about the same. So basically what we need from the topic creator is the 1. Service Bus namespace and queue details (queue name) and 2. Connection url (to get started and establish the connection) ?